# How to enable otg in moto e

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, operating-system

I am using MOTO-E  and working on lollipop OS.
Here, OTG is not supporting. I have read it from google which Moto-E doesn't support OTG.

My question is

Will oTG work on OS 4.4 (Kitkat)?

How to downgrade OS from 5.1 to 4.4?

Comment: You can try to root the device and use app Stickmount.

Answer (score 1):

[Moto E's hardware doesn't support OTG](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-E-1st-Gen/Is-there-USB-OTG-support-in-Moto-E/m-p/3180373), that is, USB Host Mode is not supported..
So there's no way to use OTG in Moto E, even if rooted or using any apps..

You can test for compatibility if you wish using **[USB Host Diagnostics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics) app** if you're rooted.